# Remove characters before a comma in a string

Tags: java, string

I was wondering what would be the best way to go about removing characters before a comma in a string, as well as removing the comma itself, leaving just the characters after the comma in the string, if the string is represented as 'city,country'.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: regular expressions are your friend

Answer (score 35, accepted):

So you want

> city,country

to become

> country

An easy way to do this is this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("city,country".replaceAll(".*,", ""));
}
```

This is **"greedy"** though, meaning it will change

> city,state,country

into

> country

In your case, you might want it to become

> state,country

I couldn't tell from your question.

If you want **"non-greedy"** matching, use

```
System.out.println("city,state,country".replaceAll(".*?,", ""));
```

this will output

> state, country

Comment: What is `.*,`? Thanks!

Comment: On a side not if he wanted >city,state,country to become 

    > state,country 

change `replaceAll` to `replaceFirst`  `System.out.println("city,state,country".replaceFirst(".*,", ""));`

But yes the question is unclear

Comment: @RuchirBaronia The period is any character, the asterisk indicates repetition (meaning any number of periods/characters), and the comma is a regular comma so the wildcard .* only precedes it.

Comment: @CodeMonkey: Your statement is untrue, because the asterisk in combination with a dot makes the regex greedy. To make it work, you could use: `"city,state,country".replaceFirst("\\w*,", "")`.

Comment: @JacobvanLingen Indeed I was wrong. Thank you for calling that out

Comment: GreateAnswer Sir Thank you

Answer (score 4):

If what you are interested in is extracting data while leaving the original string intact you should use the split(String regex) function.

```
String foo = new String("city,country");
String[] data = foo.split(",");
```

The data array will now contain strings "city" and "country".
More info is available here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Strings are immutable, so the original string will always be left intact.

Answer (score 4):

check this

```
String s="city,country";
System.out.println(s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(',')+1));
```

I found it faster than `.replaceAll(".*,", "")`

Comment: What is '.*,'? THanks

Comment: it is regex ".*" for any number of character and ',' comma used as delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a combination of `substring` and `indexOf`, using `indexOf` to determine the position of the (first) comma, and `substring` to extract a portion of the string relative to that position.

```
String s = "city,country";
String s2 = s.substring(s.indexOf(",") + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a sort of substring that finds all the indexes of characters before your comma and then all you'd need to do is remove them.